# gulp tasks sharing a common setting without a global object

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, global

I have a number of gulp tasks each residing in its own file (using the require-dir module) rather than a monolithic file.

I am using modules for configuration settings instead of json files (which I prefer for comments and for derived values).

To keep things simple here is an example setup with a single key I need to share/set between the gulp tasks.

/config/index.js

```
var config = {}

config.buildType  = '';  // set this to either 'dev' or 'dist'

module.exports = config;
```

here is default task for which I want to set config.buildType to 'dev'

default.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var config = require('../config/');

gulp.task('default', ['build'], function(cb) {
});
```

here is a deploy task for which I want to set buildType to 'dist'

deploy.js

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var config = require('../config/');

gulp.task('deploy-s3', ['build'], function() {

});
```

here is a build task that I want to change based on buildType

build.js

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var config = require('../config/');

gulp.task('build', function(cb) {

console.log('in build',config.buildType);
if (config.buildType == 'dev') runSequence('clean',['sass',config.htmlGenerator], 'watch', cb);
if (config.buildType == 'dist') runSequence('clean',['sass',config.htmlGenerator], cb);
});
```

**So here is the issue**   If I set `config.buildType` in default.js or deploy.js outside gulp.task then since they are all lumped into essentially one file by require-dir the value is simply whichever file was loaded last. If I set it inside the gulp.task function I am confused about about the timing/scope of that setting.

**Update**:  Found this related issue https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/193. It was pointed out in this issue the task function starts after all the queued tasks so that means I can't set something inside the task function and expect it to be executed before the listed tasks (in my case 'build')

one poster made a task to set a parameter like this

```
gulp.task('set-dist', function () {
  config.buildType = 'dist';
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['set-dist', 'build']);
```

So some advice.....  do I go the way of this "hack" or is there some better way to do this??

(fyi, I am just a couple months into learning node/javascript on my own so my experience is limited)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process.env` to hold config attributes for your project. Check [this](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

In your case you can do:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  runSequence('clean',['sass',config.htmlGenerator], 'watch', cb);
} else {
  runSequence('clean',['sass',config.htmlGenerator], cb);
}
});
```

- `gulp build NODE_ENV=production` for production
- or `gulp build NODE_ENV=development`.

This will play nicely with existing CI tools like Travis.

Comment: this might be helpful but it still has the same issue.   If I set a value for process.env.buildType outside a task function it's just the last that is set that is used and if I do it inside a gulp task function then it's not set before build is called.  BTW I have more than just dev/production switch to set I only provided a simple example of what I am after.

Comment: I updated my question, so that my issue is more clear and referenced an issue and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with this dropping the 'build' task altogether.  It will hopefully work in some similar form after gulp 4.0 is released.  It allows me to modify any setting before calling other tasks.  Can use it with gulpif in tasks like my 'sass' task which is a pipe only task.  Still wondering if there is a "better" way.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var config = require('../config/');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
config.buildType='dev'
config.url = 'http://localhost:' + config.localport;
runSequence('clean',['sass',config.htmlGenerator],'watch', cb);
});
```